# Overflow:hidden stop's me from scrolling down the rest of my web page

Tags: html, css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Lobster|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Roboto+Condensed&display=swap');
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    background-color: #e0e0d1;
}
nav.Top-Nav.container {
   border-radius: 7px;
}
.Top-Nav {
 display: flex;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: #131930;
 max-width: 1140px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-height: 60px;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
div.brandName {
 font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
 font-size: 20px;
}
div.brandName span#cap {
    font-size: 50px;
}
ul.List a {
   font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
div.brandName, ul.List a {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #acaaaf;

}
span#frm-style {
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
 color: cadetblue;
    font-size: 25px;
}
ul.List {
 display: flex;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 
}
ul.List a {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 34px;
}
.dropdown-icon {
 display: none;
}
div.offer-note {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
div.offer-note1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
div.offer-note1 p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    color: #629fa3;
    font-size: 15px;
    
}
button.offer-btn1 {
    background-color: cadetblue;
    border-radius: 7px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 23px;
}

div.offer-note p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 140px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #629fa3;
    font-size: 15px;
    
}
span.click-offer {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 5px black;
}
button.offer-btn {
    margin-left: 98px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    border-radius: 7px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px bold;
}
button.offer-btn:hover{
    background-color: #0f2729;
    color: whitesmoke;
}
div.fish-toon4 {
    width: 80%;
}
iframe.Fish-vid1 {
    width: 90%;
    height: 400px;
}
img.sec2-firstfish-pic {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70%;
    height: 600px;
}
h1.about-me {
    font-size: 70px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
div.fishem img.fish-pic {
    height: 80%;
    max-width: 100px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
/*
############ COLUM ##################
.col-1{width:8.33%;}
.col-2{width:16.66%;}
.col-3{width:25%;}
.col-4{width:33.33%;}
.col-5{width:41.66%;}
.col-6{width:50%;}
.col-7{width:58.33;}
.col-8{width:66.66%;}
.col-9{width:75%;}
.col-10{width:83.33%;}
.col-11{width:91.66%;}
.col-12{width:100%;}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}
.row::after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}
*/
/*##############MOBILE#################*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    ul.List li a.nav-link {
        list-style: none;
        display: none;
    }
     ul.List.responsive li.show-responsive a {
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
    }
}









@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    ul.List li a.nav-link {
        list-style: none;
        display: none;
    }

  ul.List.responsive li a.nav-link {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.List li.dropdown-icon {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 right: 10px;
}
ul.List.responsive {
   flex-direction: column;

  }
 ul.List.responsive li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
   list-style: none;
 }
    img.fish-pic {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
    }
    button.offer-btn {
        margin-left: 193px;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    div.offer-note p {
        padding-top: 30px;

    }
    iframe.Fish-vid1 {
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
    div.fish-toon4 {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
    div.fish-toon4 img.fish-pik {
    margin-left: 70px;
}
    button.offer-btn1 {
        margin-left: 100px;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>CribFarm</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.0.0-dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.0.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
   <nav class="Top-Nav  container ">
    <div class="brandName"><span id="cap">c</span>rib<span id="frm-style">Farm</span></div>
    <ul class="List" id="dropDownclick">
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a></li>
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Our goal</a></li>
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Who we are</a></li>
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown-icon"><a onclick="dropDownMenu()" href="#" >&#9776</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
    <hr>

    
<!--    ##################  section2 ###############-->
    <div class="container-fliud">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
        <img  class="sec2-firstfish-pic" src="assets/_private_var_mobile_Containers_Data_001%20(1).jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <hr>
    
    <!--    #######section1################-->
    <div class="container-fliud" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-3">
<div class="offer-note">
    <p> 
       <span class="click-offer">Talk</span> to me.
    </p>
</div>
            <button class="offer-btn">Click here!</button>
    </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
                <iframe class="Fish-vid1" src="assets/fish-video.mp4"></iframe>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3 ">
                <div class="fish-toon4">
                <img  class="fish-pik"  src="assets/fish-toon4.jpeg">
    <div class="offer-note1">
    <p> 
       <span class="click-offer">Click!</span> for special offers
    </p>
</div>
    <button class="offer-btn1">Click now!</button>
                    
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    
    
    
    
    
<!--    ############### section 3 #################-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9" width="100%" hight="300px" background-color="cadetblue">
               <div class="my-abt-div"><h1 class="about-me">Tips</h1></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum..</p>
                
                
                
<!--
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 fishem">
            <img class="fish-pic" src="assets/download%20(1).jpeg">
            </div>
-->
          
        </div>
    </div>



















<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
  </div>
</div>
    
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="farm.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-4.0.0-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        
        
</body>
</html>
```

I'm actually new to coding and while practicing I tried making my page mobile responsive and noticed spacing at the right side of my web page, make the page scroll to the right. I then grabbed the html and body in my CSS and added the following properties, height:100%, width:100%, margin and padding of 0px and finally the overflow: hidden; property. at this point, it solved my problem of the webpage scrolling to the right but now I can scroll at all to the rest of the page. would really appreciate it if someone could advise me on a possible solution.

Comment: Please provide your complete HTML/CSS in the question body, we cannot assist you with a programmatic question without code. Thanks

Comment: Try setting overflow: auto, that should make it so that when there's more content it will show the scroll bar. And if the content does not exceed the parent, no scroll bar is shown.

Comment: That's what `overflow: hidden` do. Use `overflow-x:hidden` to prevent scrolling on x axis only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution here is to change `overflow: hidden` to only hide the overflow on the X axis: `overflow-x: hidden`.

*Note that `height: 100%; width: 100%;` both seem unnecessary and from my quick test can be removed (but always check cross browser inconsistencies).*

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower|Lobster|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Roboto+Condensed&display=swap');
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
html,body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
    background-color: #e0e0d1;
}
nav.Top-Nav.container {
   border-radius: 7px;
}
.Top-Nav {
 display: flex;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: #131930;
 max-width: 1140px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-height: 60px;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
div.brandName {
 font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
 font-size: 20px;
}
div.brandName span#cap {
    font-size: 50px;
}
ul.List a {
   font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
div.brandName, ul.List a {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #acaaaf;

}
span#frm-style {
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
 color: cadetblue;
    font-size: 25px;
}
ul.List {
 display: flex;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 
}
ul.List a {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 34px;
}
.dropdown-icon {
 display: none;
}
div.offer-note {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
div.offer-note1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
div.offer-note1 p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    color: #629fa3;
    font-size: 15px;
    
}
button.offer-btn1 {
    background-color: cadetblue;
    border-radius: 7px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 23px;
}

div.offer-note p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 140px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #629fa3;
    font-size: 15px;
    
}
span.click-offer {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 5px black;
}
button.offer-btn {
    margin-left: 98px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    border-radius: 7px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px bold;
}
button.offer-btn:hover{
    background-color: #0f2729;
    color: whitesmoke;
}
div.fish-toon4 {
    width: 80%;
}
iframe.Fish-vid1 {
    width: 90%;
    height: 400px;
}
img.sec2-firstfish-pic {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70%;
    height: 600px;
}
h1.about-me {
    font-size: 70px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
div.fishem img.fish-pic {
    height: 80%;
    max-width: 100px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
/*
############ COLUM ##################
.col-1{width:8.33%;}
.col-2{width:16.66%;}
.col-3{width:25%;}
.col-4{width:33.33%;}
.col-5{width:41.66%;}
.col-6{width:50%;}
.col-7{width:58.33;}
.col-8{width:66.66%;}
.col-9{width:75%;}
.col-10{width:83.33%;}
.col-11{width:91.66%;}
.col-12{width:100%;}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}
.row::after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}
*/
/*##############MOBILE#################*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    ul.List li a.nav-link {
        list-style: none;
        display: none;
    }
     ul.List.responsive li.show-responsive a {
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
    }
}









@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    ul.List li a.nav-link {
        list-style: none;
        display: none;
    }

  ul.List.responsive li a.nav-link {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.List li.dropdown-icon {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 right: 10px;
}
ul.List.responsive {
   flex-direction: column;

  }
 ul.List.responsive li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
   list-style: none;
 }
    img.fish-pic {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
    }
    button.offer-btn {
        margin-left: 193px;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    div.offer-note p {
        padding-top: 30px;

    }
    iframe.Fish-vid1 {
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
    div.fish-toon4 {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
    div.fish-toon4 img.fish-pik {
    margin-left: 70px;
}
    button.offer-btn1 {
        margin-left: 100px;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>CribFarm</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.0.0-dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.0.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
   <nav class="Top-Nav  container ">
    <div class="brandName"><span id="cap">c</span>rib<span id="frm-style">Farm</span></div>
    <ul class="List" id="dropDownclick">
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a></li>
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Our goal</a></li>
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Who we are</a></li>
     <li class="show-responsive"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown-icon"><a onclick="dropDownMenu()" href="#" >&#9776</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
    <hr>

    
<!--    ##################  section2 ###############-->
    <div class="container-fliud">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8">
        <img  class="sec2-firstfish-pic" src="assets/_private_var_mobile_Containers_Data_001%20(1).jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <hr>
    
    <!--    #######section1################-->
    <div class="container-fliud" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-3">
<div class="offer-note">
    <p> 
       <span class="click-offer">Talk</span> to me.
    </p>
</div>
            <button class="offer-btn">Click here!</button>
    </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
                <iframe class="Fish-vid1" src="assets/fish-video.mp4"></iframe>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3 ">
                <div class="fish-toon4">
                <img  class="fish-pik"  src="assets/fish-toon4.jpeg">
    <div class="offer-note1">
    <p> 
       <span class="click-offer">Click!</span> for special offers
    </p>
</div>
    <button class="offer-btn1">Click now!</button>
                    
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    
    
    
    
    
<!--    ############### section 3 #################-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9" width="100%" hight="300px" background-color="cadetblue">
               <div class="my-abt-div"><h1 class="about-me">Tips</h1></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum..</p>
                
                
                
<!--
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 fishem">
            <img class="fish-pic" src="assets/download%20(1).jpeg">
            </div>
-->
          
        </div>
    </div>



















<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
  </div>
</div>
    
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="farm.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-4.0.0-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        
        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put everything from the `<body>` inside a div. This div would have `position: fixed` or `absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; left:` and not `overflow`

Tell me if this works for you

Comment: No need to use fixed or absolute positioning here, and I'm not sure that'll solve the OP's problem either.